# Unknown device or simulator UDID using Xcode Simulator

Tags: simulator, appium-ios

I am running Appium scripts on IntelliJ, I am using Xcode simulator. Though I am giving correct UDID in properties file, I am always getting this issue.

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: '1685524E-A876-4CEB-9C75-C0C1FA0EB018'

Comment: Hi Anusha, welcome to stack overflow. Please read guide on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and follow on how to ask question properly. Please add description, goal and your tests in question to help understand properly.

Comment: I am running Appium scripts on IntelliJ, I am using Xcode simulator. Though I am giving correct UDID in properties file, I am always getting this issue.